# How to handle the dialog "Allow site to store data in persistent storage?" in Firefox using Playwright?

Tags: e2e, playwright

I would like to handle this popping out dialog in Firefox browser and allow storing data in persistent storage in Playwright's E2E tests.

[image: Dialog with persistent storage question]

Currently, this lack of permission interrupts my tests. How can I configure it in Playwright to allow it by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow storing data in persistent storage by default, it needs to be configured in `playwright.config.js` file. It needs to be configured like this under `projects` section:

```js
projects: [
  {
    name: 'firefox',
    use: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      launchOptions: {
        firefoxUserPrefs: {
          'permissions.default.persistent-storage': 1
        },
      },
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the "Allow site to store data in persistent storage?" dialog in Firefox using Playwright, you can use the `setPermissions` method to grant persistent storage permission to the browser. Here's a step-by-step solution:

1 Launch the Firefox browser with the required context and page:

```
const { firefox } = require('playwright');

async function runTest() {
  const browser = await firefox.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  
  // Proceed with your test steps
}

runTest();
```

2 Set the persistent storage permission to "granted" using the `setPermissions` method:

```
await context.setPermissions(['persistent-storage']);
```

3 Handle the dialog using the `onDialog` event:

```
context.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
  if (dialog.type() === 'alert' && dialog.defaultValue().includes('Allow site to store data in persistent storage?')) {
    await dialog.accept();
  } else {
    await dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```

4 Navigate to your desired URL and continue with your test steps:

```
await page.goto('https://example.com');
// Perform your test actions on the page
```

By setting the permission to `persistent-storage` and handling the dialog using the `onDialog` event, you can automatically allow the site to store data in persistent storage during your Playwright tests in Firefox.

Remember to adapt this solution to fit within your existing test framework and incorporate it into your test scripts accordingly.

I hope this solution helps you handle the "Allow site to store data in persistent storage?" dialog in Firefox using Playwright. Let me know if you have any further questions!